# Seeking to prove Continuity of $f(x) =\frac{x}{1+||x||}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

> > How would I prove that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow B(\theta,1)$, where $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+||x||}$, is continuous?

For metric spaces, I understand that if $f(x)$ is continuous at a point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta > 0$ such that if $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d(x,p)<\delta$, then $d^{'}(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon.$

Thus I tried the following. Let $\left| x-p\right|<\delta$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left| f(x)-f(p)\right|&=&\left| \frac{x}{1+||x||}-\frac{p}{1+||p||}\right|\\
&=&\left| \frac{x(1+||p||)-p(1+||x||)}{(1+||x||)(1+||p||)} \right|\\
&\leq&  \frac{1}{(1+||x||)(1+||p||)} \left|(x(1+||p||)-p(1+||x||)\right|\\
&=& \frac{1}{(1+||x||)(1+||p||)} \left|(x-p+x||p||-p||x||)\right|\\
&\leq& \frac{1}{(1+||x||)(1+||p||)} \left(\left|(x-p)\right|+ \left|(x||p||-p||x||)\right|\right)\\
&<&\frac{1}{(1+||x||)(1+||p||)} \left(\delta+ 2||p||||x||)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

This is where I am stuck. Any suggestions?

---

I want to thank you for taking the time to read this question. I greatly appreciate any assistance you provide.

Comment: Given an $\epsilon >0$ pick a $\delta >0$ (usually in terms of $\epsilon$) which works. Your work may suggest a good choice for $\delta$.

Comment: You could also skip the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ by using continuity of a composition, since $||x||$ is continuous and $1+||x||>0$.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I do not want to prove things using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions unless I absolutelly have to, and this is a case where it is not necesary.

The function $g_1:\mathbb R^n \to [0,\infty)$, defined as $g_1(x) = ||x||$ is continuous.

The function $g_2:[0,\infty)\to [1,\infty)$, defined as $g_2(y) = y + 1$ is continuous.

The function $g_3:[1, \infty)\to \mathbb R$, defined as $g_3(z) = \frac1z$ is continuous.

Therefore, the function $g=g_3\circ g_2\circ g_1$, which is equal to

$$g(x) = g_3(g_2(g_1(x))) = g_3(g_2(||x||)) = g_3(||x|| + 1) = \frac{1}{||x|| + 1}$$

is continuous.

---

Your function is equal to the product of the identity function and $g$, so it is also continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Undo your last inequality and consider:

$$\big|x|p|| - p||x||\big| = \big|\big|\ x||p|| - p||p|| + p||p|| - p||x|| \ \big|\big| $$
$$\leq ||p||\cdot ||x-p|| + ||p||\big|||x|| - ||p||\big| \leq ||p||\cdot ||x-p|| + ||p|| \cdot ||x-p||$$